# onclicklistner on videoview in recyclerview

Tags: java, android, firebase, uri, android-videoview

hi i am building a app where, i show videos from firebase to videoview which is in recyclerview in gridlayout form, means at each fragment there are two videos shown, i want to add on clicklisten to them as when someone click on it, a new activity opens and at that activity, the same video is shown in fullscreen (vertically). i used putextra to transfer my data, but i am getting error, "uristring",

bellow is my code

**Adapter code**

```
package com.example.godhelpme.Adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.VideoView;

  import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
  import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
   import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
  import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;
  import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

   import com.example.godhelpme.Fragments.HomeFragment;
   import com.example.godhelpme.FullScreen;
   import com.example.godhelpme.LoginActivity;
   import com.example.godhelpme.MainActivity;
   import com.example.godhelpme.Model.Post;
   import com.example.godhelpme.Model.User;
   import com.example.godhelpme.R;
   import com.example.godhelpme.StartActivity;
 

  import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
  import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
  import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
  import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
  import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
  import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;


 import java.util.List;

 public class PostAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PostAdapter.ViewHolder>{

private Context mContext;
private List<Post> mPosts;

private FirebaseUser firebaseUser;


public PostAdapter(Context mContext, List<Post> mPosts) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.mPosts = mPosts;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.upload_item, parent,false);
    return new PostAdapter.ViewHolder(view);


}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

Post post = mPosts.get(position);

 try {
     String link = post.getVideourl();
     MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(mContext);
     mediaController.setAnchorView(holder.video1);
     Uri video = Uri.parse(link);
     holder.video1.setMediaController(mediaController);
     holder.video1.setVideoURI(video);


     holder.video1.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
         @Override
         public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {

             try {
                 if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                     mediaPlayer.stop();
                     mediaPlayer.release();
                     mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                 }
                 mediaPlayer.setVolume(0f, 0f);
                 mediaPlayer.setLooping(false);
                 mediaPlayer.start();
             } catch (Exception e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }

             mediaController.setVisibility(View.GONE);

         }
     });

     holder.video1.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
         @Override
         public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
             mediaPlayer.start();             }
     });




     holder.id.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View view) {
             Intent in = new Intent(view.getContext(),FullScreen.class);
             in.putExtra(" videourl", post.getVideourl());
             in.putExtra("publisher", post.getPublisher());
             in.putExtra("postid", post.getPostid());

             view.getContext().startActivity(in);
         }
     });







 }catch (Exception e){
     Toast.makeText(mContext,e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }







    














   FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(post.getPublisher())
   .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);
          holder.id.setText(user.getUsername());


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mPosts.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public VideoView video1;

    public TextView id;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        video1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.video1);



        id = itemView.findViewById(R.id.id);


    }
   }
```

}

**THAT ACTIVITY CODE WHERE I WANT TO SHOW**

```
  package com.example.godhelpme;

    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

    import android.content.Context;
       import android.content.Intent;
   import android.media.MediaPlayer;
       import android.net.Uri;
       import android.os.Bundle;
     import android.widget.MediaController;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;
      import android.widget.VideoView;

      import com.example.godhelpme.Model.Post;

     import java.net.URISyntaxException;
      import java.util.ArrayList;
      import java.util.List;
```

public class FullScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

```
 VideoView videoFull;
 TextView idFull;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_full_screen);

    videoFull = findViewById(R.id.videoFull);
    idFull = findViewById(R.id.idFull);


    Intent in = getIntent();

    try{
    String ttr = in.getStringExtra("videourl");
    MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(videoFull);
    Uri video1 = Uri.parse(ttr);
    videoFull.setMediaController(mediaController);
    videoFull.setVideoURI(video1);
   }catch (Exception e){
  Toast.makeText(this,e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }



    videoFull.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            mediaPlayer.start();             }
    });



    idFull.setText(in.getStringExtra("publisher"));



}
```

}

**PLEASE HELP GUYS PLEASE**

Answer (score 0):

It took me three days to figure out what's the problem in my code. After knowing my mistake i am feeling very ashamed as well as happy that i figured, it out.
the mistake is in the adapter code,

```
 in.putExtra(" videourl", post.getVideourl());

  String ttr = in.getStringExtra("videourl");
```

the difference between above two code line is the, in first line there is space before the videourl and in the second line there is no space before videourl, and that's a problem. :-)